# How to view Performance Counter data?

Tags: .net, performancecounter

I have created a couple of performance counters to count the requests made to a third party web service and number of errors reported by these web services.

I am incrementing these performance counters correctly in my asp.net code, I can see these counters in my Visual Studio Server Explorer.

I can see these are listed in my perfmon but am not sure how to exactly view the current count?

Whats the best way to view these manually and programatically download these in a database?